# Send to all users in room socket io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

am trying to join user to room then send a massage to all users in that room, but its not work .
any idea would help alot .

Server side :

```
let users = {};
let customerId = {};

io.on('connection', function (socket) {

  socket.on('AllUsers' , function (data){
    console.log(data);
    customerId[socket.id] = data.userId
    socket.join("customer");
  
   });

    io.sockets.in("customer").emit('chat',"hi");
});
```

Client side:

```
<script src = "/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

<script>
     const socket = io();
     socket.emit('AllUsers',{userId:'customer1323456'});
     
      socket.on("chat", function (arg) {
      console.log("clientererer" , arg); 
      const gg = document.getElementById('gg').textContent = arg ;
      });
     
     function myFunction() {
     
     }
  </script>
```

Comment: "but its not work" And what works not?!

Answer (score 1):

You can send messages to all users who has joined the room by:

```
io.of("/roomName").emit("eventName", "message");
```

for your case :

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {

  socket.on('AllUsers' , function (data){
    console.log(data);
    customerId[socket.id] = data.userId
    socket.join("customer");
    io.of("/customer").emit("chat", "hi");
   });
});
```

for more info :